# Display two bar charts one by one in MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am plotting bar charts using pivot tables. I have two independent pivot tables and need to produce two bar charts side-by-side and save it as a PNG image. Using this code, the chart is generated but it won't display as expected.

What I tried:

```
# Plotting Activity Begins
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
    vig = task_frame.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(8, 6), stacked=True, width=0.3, rot=20)
    print "ax1",ax1
    print "vig",vig
    vicky = issue_frame.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(8, 6), stacked=True, width=0.3, rot=90)
    print "ax2",ax2
    print "vicky",vicky
    plt.ylim((0, 10))
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
    plt.savefig("/tmp/" + str(current_date) + ".png")
```

My print statement values:

```
ax1 Axes(0.125,0.1;0.352273x0.8)
vig Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
ax2 Axes(0.125,0.536364;0.352273x0.363636)
vicky Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
```

How can I display the charts as side-by-side pictures in a single image? Where should I assign the ax1 and ax2 value?

Comment: You want two subplots on one image?

Comment: Yes in single image, I like to have two subplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you plot try to add axes instance to plot function, like here:

```
...
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
task_frame.plot(..., ax=ax1)
issue_frame.plot(..., ax=ax2)
...
```